# Converting a String array into an int Array in java

Tags: java

I am new to java programming. My question is this I have a `String` array but when I am trying to convert it to an `int` array I keep getting

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException
```

My code is

```
private void processLine(String[] strings) {
    Integer[] intarray=new Integer[strings.length];
    int i=0;
    for(String str:strings){
        intarray[i]=Integer.parseInt(str);//Exception in this line
        i++;
    }
}
```

Any help would be great thanks!!!

Comment: What are the strings you pass in?

Comment: "The characters in the string must all be decimal digits, except that the first character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a negative value. The resulting integer value is returned, exactly as if the argument and the radix 10 were given as arguments to the parseInt(java.lang.String, int) method.
" http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)

Comment: That happens when the string is not a properly formatted integer.  Also, you should probably use `int[]` not `Integer[]`.

Comment: Hi Found the error there was a trailing "\r" in the string array.so 3 was taken as "3\r".I removed the trailing \r and it worked Thanks

Comment: Please copy/paste exception and error messages in future.  You can edit your question to add those details.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To get rid of additional whitespace, you could change the code like this:

```
intarray[i]=Integer.parseInt(str.trim()); // No more Exception in this line
```

Answer (score 116):

Suppose, for example, that we have a arrays of strings:

```
String[] strings = {"1", "2", "3"};
```

With ***Lambda Expressions*** <sup>[[1]](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) [[2]](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html)</sup> (since Java 8), you can do the next **▼**:

```java
int[] array = Arrays.asList(strings).stream().mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

**▼** This is another way:

```java
int[] array = Arrays.stream(strings).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

<sub>—————————

*Notes*

  1. [Lambda Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) in [*The Java Tutorials*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html).

  2. [Java SE 8: Lambda Quick Start](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html)</sub>

Comment: how to use same lambda expressions to convert string array to Integer object array?

Comment: @ffguven I feel autoboxing should take care of that whenever the need arises, or am I missing something?

Comment: @ffguven okay one year later, I stumble upon the same thread, I look at my previous comment and realise I was actually missing something. 
One way(idk if it's the best way) to do so would be : 
`Integer[] array = Arrays.stream(strings).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);`

Answer (score 12):

To help debug, and make your code better, do this:

```
private void processLine(String[] strings) {
    Integer[] intarray=new Integer[strings.length];
    int i=0;
    for(String str:strings){
        try {
            intarray[i]=Integer.parseInt(str);
            i++;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a number: " + str + " at index " + i, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, from a code neatness point, you could reduce the lines by doing this:

```
for (String str : strings)
    intarray[i++] = Integer.parseInt(str);
```

Comment: I would advise against your "code neatness" proposal - it makes the code more confusing, not more neat.

Comment: I find the "neater" code perfectly readable.  Concise code can look quite nice.  :)

Comment: @La-comadreja I do not. The non-neater method is more "natural".

Answer (score 8):

Another short way:

```
int[] myIntArray = Arrays.stream(myStringArray).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are trying to get an `Integer[]` array you could use:

```
Integer[] intarray = Stream.of(strings).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

Your code:

```
private void processLine(String[] strings) {
    Integer[] intarray = Stream.of(strings).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);
}
```

Note, that this only works for Java 8 and higher.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void processLine(String[] strings) {
    Integer[] intarray=new Integer[strings.length];
    for(int i=0;i<strings.length;i++) {
        intarray[i]=Integer.parseInt(strings[i]);
    }
    for(Integer temp:intarray) {
        System.out.println("convert int array from String"+temp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class array_test {

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String line = br.readLine();

String[] s_array = line.split(" ");
```

/* Splitting the array of number 
separated by space into string array.*/

```
Integer [] a = new Integer[s_array.length];
```

/*Creating the int array of size equals to string array.*/

```
    for(int i =0; i<a.length;i++)
    {
        a[i]= Integer.parseInt(s_array[i]);// Parsing from string to int

        System.out.println(a[i]);
    }

    // your integer array is ready to use.

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This is because your string does not strictly contain the integers in string format. It has alphanumeric chars in it.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int[] strArrayToIntArray(String[] a){
    int[] b = new int[a.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        b[i] = Integer.parseInt(a[i]);
    }

    return b;
}
```

This is a simple function, that should help you. 
You can use him like this:

```
int[] arr = strArrayToIntArray(/*YOUR STR ARRAY*/);
```