# How do I create a Stream of regex matches?

Tags: java, regex, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to parse standard input and extract every string that matches with a specific pattern, count the number of occurrences of each match, and print the results alphabetically.  This problem seems like a good match for the Streams API, but I can't find a concise way to create a stream of matches from a Matcher.

I worked around this problem by implementing an iterator over the matches and wrapping it into a Stream, but the result is not very readable.  How can I create a stream of regex matches without introducing additional classes?

```java
public class PatternCounter
{
    static private class MatcherIterator implements Iterator<String> {
        private final Matcher matcher;
        public MatcherIterator(Matcher matcher) {
            this.matcher = matcher;
        }
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return matcher.find();
        }
        public String next() {
            return matcher.group(0);
        }
    }

    static public void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)");

        new TreeMap<String, Long>(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))
            .lines().map(line -> {
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
                return StreamSupport.stream(
                        Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(new MatcherIterator(matcher), Spliterator.ORDERED), false);
            }).reduce(Stream.empty(), Stream::concat).collect(groupingBy(o -> o, counting()))
        ).forEach((k, v) -> {
            System.out.printf("%s\t%s\n",k,v);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: in Java 9, there will be a method Matcher.results. see
http://download.java.net/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results--

Comment: looks like the [Java 9  URI has changed](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results--)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Well, in Java 8, there is [`Pattern.splitAsStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#splitAsStream-java.lang.CharSequence-) which will provide a stream of items split by a *delimiter* pattern but unfortunately no support method for getting a stream of *matches*.

If you are going to implement such a `Stream`, I recommend implementing `Spliterator` directly rather than implementing and wrapping an `Iterator`. You may be more familiar with `Iterator` but implementing a simple `Spliterator` is straight-forward:

```
final class MatchItr extends Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<String> {
    private final Matcher matcher;
    MatchItr(Matcher m) {
        super(m.regionEnd()-m.regionStart(), ORDERED|NONNULL);
        matcher=m;
    }
    public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super String> action) {
        if(!matcher.find()) return false;
        action.accept(matcher.group());
        return true;
    }
}
```

You may consider overriding `forEachRemaining` with a straight-forward loop, though.

---

If I understand your attempt correctly, the solution should look more like:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
                 "[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)");

try(BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(System.console().reader())) {

    br.lines()
      .flatMap(line -> StreamSupport.stream(new MatchItr(pattern.matcher(line)), false))
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o->o, TreeMap::new, Collectors.counting()))
      .forEach((k, v) -> System.out.printf("%s\t%s\n",k,v));
}
```

---

Java 9 provides a method [`Stream<MatchResult> results()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results--) directly on the `Matcher`. But for finding matches within a stream, there’s [an even more convenient method on `Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#findAll-java.util.regex.Pattern-). With that, the implementation simplifies to

```
try(Scanner s = new Scanner(System.console().reader())) {
    s.findAll(pattern)
     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MatchResult::group,TreeMap::new,Collectors.counting()))
     .forEach((k, v) -> System.out.printf("%s\t%s\n",k,v));
}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42978216/2711488) contains a back-port of `Scanner.findAll` that can be used with Java 8.

Comment: You can add the NONNULL characteristic as well.  I'm not sure if you can add IMMUTABLE or not; the Matcher documentation is not clear if modifying the underlying CharSequence object (which may be StringBuilder) during the match results in defined behavior.

Comment: @Jeffrey: indeed, `NONNULL` is possible, `IMMUTABLE` could be specified if the source is a `String` *and* you have full control over the `Matcher` as the `Matcher`’s properties must not be changed as well (most notably its source), but specifying these flags is not that important as currently, no-one makes use of these flags…

Comment: "unfortunately no support method for getting a stream of matches." I have _never_ understood this omission. The Java designers must have something against this, but who knows what it is. Splitting is not the same, as empty strings in the beginning of the match array are common. Sigh.

Comment: @Ray Toal: [there will be](http://download.java.net/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results--) in Java 9…

Comment: @Holger  looks like the [Java 9  URI has changed](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results--)

Comment: @Gary: I integrated it into the answer, so it’s easier to find. Comments can’t be updated after such a long time, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I find it incredibly clear and useful !

Comment: @Gary The URL has changed again. They moved it [to here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results--).

Comment: @MCEmperor that’s the one I edited into my answer 1½ years ago…

Answer (score 4):

Going off of Holger's solution, we can support arbitrary `Matcher` operations (such as getting the *n*th group) by having the user provide a `Function<Matcher, String>` operation. We can also hide the `Spliterator` as an implementation detail, so that callers can just work with the `Stream` directly. As a rule of thumb `StreamSupport` should be used by library code, rather than users.

```
public class MatcherStream {
  private MatcherStream() {}

  public static Stream<String> find(Pattern pattern, CharSequence input) {
    return findMatches(pattern, input).map(MatchResult::group);
  }

  public static Stream<MatchResult> findMatches(
      Pattern pattern, CharSequence input) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

    Spliterator<MatchResult> spliterator = new Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<MatchResult>(
        Long.MAX_VALUE, Spliterator.ORDERED|Spliterator.NONNULL) {
      @Override
      public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super MatchResult> action) {
        if(!matcher.find()) return false;
        action.accept(matcher.toMatchResult());
        return true;
      }};

    return StreamSupport.stream(spliterator, false);
  }
}
```

You can then use it like so:

```
MatcherStream.find(Pattern.compile("\\w+"), "foo bar baz").forEach(System.out::println);
```

Or for your specific task (borrowing again from Holger):

```
try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(System.console().reader())) {
  br.lines()
    .flatMap(line -> MatcherStream.find(pattern, line))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o->o, TreeMap::new, Collectors.counting()))
    .forEach((k, v) -> System.out.printf("%s\t%s\n", k, v));
}
```

Comment: better to just make it a `Stream<MatchResult>` I think. You don't want to allow functions that mutate the `Match`, and then you can map it to a `Stream<String>` to satisfy OP using `Stream::map`

Comment: also, find() should accept CharSequence parameter, not only String

Comment: @PatrickParker good suggestions, I hadn't noticed `MatchResult`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a `Scanner` together with regular expressions using the `findWithinHorizon` method you could also convert a regular expression into a stream of strings.
Here we use a stream builder which is very convenient to use during a conventional `while` loop.

Here is an example:

```
private Stream<String> extractRulesFrom(String text, Pattern pattern, int group) {
    Stream.Builder<String> builder = Stream.builder();
    try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(text)) {
        while (scanner.findWithinHorizon(pattern, 0) != null) {
            builder.accept(scanner.match().group(group));
        }
    }
    return builder.build();
}
```