# Java 8 Streams: How to read lines between two lines specified by line content

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Input to the current problem statement is -

**Input.txt**

```
#START_OF_TEST_CASES

#DATA
key1:VA1
key2:VA2
key3:VA3
key4:VA4
key5:VA5
#DEND

#ENTRIES:
1{key1}{key1}{key3}
2{key2}{key2}{key1}
3{key3}{key1}{key2}
#EEND
```

Now I want to read this file and create a HashMap of the lines in between **#DATA** and **#DEND**. Key for the HashMap is the left part of ':' and value is the right part. Although we can achieve this iteratively I want to do this using Java 8's Stream APIs.

Comment: great, what have you done so far to solve this?

Comment: Streams is not the answer to everything. This is a great example where Streams is not the right tool for the job. You can do it by writing your own collector or your own stateful filter, but you'd end up with more (and more complex) code than a normal loop, so why do it? It would also fail badly if the stream is parallel, *yikes*!

Comment: Java 9: `Files.lines(path) .dropWhile(s -> !s.equals("#DATA")) .skip(1) .takeWhile(s -> !s.equals("#DEND")) …`, Java 8: wait for Java 9. Regarding how to split and store into a `Map`, there are already several questions with answers.

Comment: Ok, here Java 8 workaround to get the stream: `Arrays.stream(new Scanner(path) .findWithinHorizon("(?<=\\R#DATA\\R)(.|\\R)*(?=\\R#DEND\\R)", 0).split("\\R")) …`

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, Java 8 streams do not support such extraction of elements in-between two matches. In Java 9, you could use

```
Map<String,String> map;
try(Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(path)) {
    map = stream
        .dropWhile(s -> !s.equals("#DATA")).skip(1)
        .takeWhile(s -> !s.equals("#DEND"))
        .filter(Pattern.compile("^[^#].*:").asPredicate())
        .map(item -> item.split(":", 2))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(parts->parts[0], parts->parts[1]));
}
// use the map
map.forEach((k,v)->System.out.println(k+" -> "+v));
```

`dropWhile` will drop all elements before the first matching element, `skip(1)` will skip the matching element, `takeWhile` effectively removes all elements after the first element matching the end criteria.

The next `filter` step using the pattern `^[^#].*:` will skip all lines starting with `#` or not containing a `:`. The remaining steps are straight-forward. When specifying a limit of `2` to `split`, it will not search for subsequent `:`s after encountering the first `:`.

Under Java 8, extracting the part between the two matches can be implemented with a `Scanner` before the stream operation:

```
String part;
try(Scanner s = new Scanner(path)) {
    part = s.findWithinHorizon("(?<=\\R#DATA\\R)(.|\\R)*(?=\\R#DEND\\R)", 0);
}
Map<String,String> map = Pattern.compile("\\R").splitAsStream(part)
    .filter(Pattern.compile("^[^#].*:").asPredicate())
    .map(item -> item.split(":", 2))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(parts->parts[0], parts->parts[1]));
// use the map
map.forEach((k,v)->System.out.println(k+" -> "+v));
```

Comment: I would go with a `findAll` addition in java-9 that could be applicable  here I think; and that regex... a couple of lookarounds, a `\\R` introduced in java-8... beautiful overall!

Comment: @Eugene: when there can be multiple occurrences of this section, `findAll()` is the way to go. And for Java 8, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42978216/2711488) provides the `findAll` operation.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the lies between **#DATA** and **#DEND** contain ':' therefore I came up with the following solution -

```
    File file = new File("Input.txt");
    try {
        Map<String,String> map = Files.lines(file.toPath())
                                     .filter(list -> list.contains(":"))
                                     .map(item -> item.split(":"))
                                     .filter(arr -> arr.length > 1)
                                     .collect(Collectors.toMap(parts->parts[0], parts->parts[1]));
        System.out.println(map.values());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The above code first filters only the lines containing colon ':', then split these lines based on the colon, after that, we filter only the list having length greater than 1 because if you see the *input.txt* file carefully, you can find that **"#ENTRIES:"** contains colon but do not contain any character after that as others do. Once we get the required data we create the HashMap.

Comment: If you know the answer why you asked the question without your code

Comment: Looks more like a stunt to answer ones own question. However, adding  additional condition `.filter(ele -> ele.contains(":") && !ele.contains("#"))` will get rid of the second filter in your answer

Comment: I did not know the answer but I came up with this answer based on the answer of [@fbokovikov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4545552/fbokovikov). Thanks to his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47912850/2704051)

Comment: @Sunil If you chose my answer as the correct one, mark it as correct and vote for him please

Comment: [@fbokovikov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4545552/fbokovikov) I did not find it right but it helped me to get my solution.

Answer (score -1):

Following code pattern resolves your problem:

```
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("Input.txt"));
    int from = lines.indexOf("#DATA") + 1;
    int to  = lines.indexOf("#DEND");
    Map<String, String> map = lines.stream()
            .skip(from)
            .limit(to - from)
            .map(s -> s.split(":"))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(pair -> pair[0], pair -> pair[1]));
```

Comment: If you have a `List` and indices, the straight-forward approach is `lines.subList(from, to).stream()`