# Iterator from object with next() and get()

Tags: collections, java-8, iterator, factory, fluent

Given an object like this:

```
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sql);
```

with usage like so:

```
Set<String> matches = new HashSet<>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    matches.add(matcher.group());
}
```

I'd like to replace this while loop by something more object-oriented like so:

```
new Iterator<String>() {
    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return matcher.find();
    }

    @Override
    public String next() {
        return matcher.group();
    }
}
```

so that I can easily e.g. make a Stream of matches, stick to using fluent APIs and such.

The thing is, I don't know and can't find a more concise way to create this Stream or Iterator. An anonymous class like above is too verbose for my taste.

I had hoped to find something like `IteratorFactory.from(matcher::find, matcher::group)` or `StreamSupport.of(matcher::find, matcher::group)` in the jdk, but so far no luck. I've no doubt libraries like apache commons or guava provide something for this, but let's say I can't use those.

Is there a convenient factory for Streams or Iterators that takes a hasNext/next method combo in the jdk?

Comment: is java-9 an option?

Comment: Side-note: both of your method implementations are wrong. They *only* work when the caller always calls `hasNext()` exactly once followed by `next()`. No other access pattern will work. Logically the `find()` method has to be executed in the `next()` method, as that's the thing that proceeds to the next result.

Comment: @JoachimSauer it's not _that_ wrong. As long as you use this iterator in the usual hasNext() -> next() way, it works fine. Calling hasNext() multiple times will screw it up, yeah, but that's not happening in my situation so it's fine.

Comment: @Marnes: I'd still flag that as an issue in a code review, because just because it works in the *current* code doesn't mean that people will think to check this when the use of your code gets extended. It's simple enough to implement that conversion *once* in one place and make sure that this `MatcherIterator` is implemented correctly. But that's a personal choice, of course.

Comment: @JoachimSauer yeah I get your point, in theory and if you want everything perfect, it wouldn't work, but in the context of my question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java-9 you could do it via:

```
Set<String> result = matcher.results()
            .map(MatchResult::group)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
System.out.println(result);
```

In java-8 you would need a back-port for this, taken from [Holger's fabulous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42961296/java-8-stream-emitting-a-stream/42978216#42978216)

**EDIT**

There is a single method btw `tryAdvance` that could incorporate `find/group`, something like this:

```
static class MyIterator extends AbstractSpliterator<String> {

    private Matcher matcher;

    public MyIterator(Matcher matcher) {
        // I can't think of a better way to estimate the size here
        // may be you can figure a better one here
        super(matcher.regionEnd() - matcher.regionStart(), 0);
        this.matcher = matcher;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super String> action) {
        while (matcher.find()) {
            action.accept(matcher.group());
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

And usage for example:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d");
Matcher m = p.matcher("12345");
Set<String> result = StreamSupport.stream(new MyIterator(m), false)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: of course! why would I be surprised that after searching such a Spliterator is already done by Holger, even better https://stackoverflow.com/a/28150956/1059372

Comment: thanks for the effort, but neither is really a solution for me. I'm on java 8, and I'd like to avoid rolling big custom code blocks for it. If it's not available ready-made in the jdk, that's just too bad then.

Comment: `matcher.regionEnd() - matcher.regionStart()` is not a bad estimate, as it denotes the maximum number of possible matches.

Comment: @Marnes so those under 20 lines of code are *big*? I bet you have other jars in your project that you use under 2% of the code they have, besides I bet you do have an `util` package... still, your choice really.

Comment: Accepting because of the java 9 stream answer. Guess I can't have the cake I wanted to have and eat it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This class I wrote embodies what I wanted to find in the jdk. Apparently though it just doesn't exist. [eugene's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50390746/1744034) offers a java 9 Stream solution though.

```
public static class SearchingIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
    private final BooleanSupplier advancer;
    private final Supplier<T> getter;

    private Optional<T> next;

    public SearchingIterator(BooleanSupplier advancer, Supplier<T> getter) {
        this.advancer = advancer;
        this.getter = getter;

        search();
    }

    private void search() {
        boolean hasNext = advancer.getAsBoolean();
        next = hasNext ? Optional.of(getter.get()) : Optional.empty();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return next.isPresent();
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        T current = next.orElseThrow(IllegalStateException::new);
        search();
        return current;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d").matcher("123");
Iterator<String> it = new SearchingIterator<>(matcher::find, matcher::group);
```