# Java-8: matching 1 pattern multiple times in 1 line in a file (via a filter)

Tags: java, java-8

Having this data file:

```
    Test 1
    Test 2 Test 3 Test 11
```

I would like to have a program to match each 'Test (.)', so I will get the output:

```
    Match: 1
    Match: 2
    Match: 3
    Match: 11
```

The program below gives this output:

```
    Match: 1
```

The program is:

```
void addMysteries( Path path, String output) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".?Test (.)");
    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines( path)) {
        lines.map( p::matcher)
                .filter(Matcher::matches)
                .forEach( matcher -> System.out.println("Match: " + matcher.group(1)));
    } catch( Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In **Java 7**, the software below is working fine. Why is this working and the above not?

```
pattern = Pattern.compile(".?Test (.)");
input = "Test 1\n\rOtherStuff\nTest 2 Test 3";
matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(  "Match: " + matcher.group( 1));
}
```

Comment: Why one is working and the other not? One is `find`ing over the whole text, the other using `matches` on each line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `Matcher` for each line, your code should look like this :

```
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path)) {
    lines.forEach(line ->
            {
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
                while (matcher.find()){
                    System.out.println("Match: " + matcher.group(1));
                }
            }
    );
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

### Java 9+ features

In Java 9+ you can use [`Matcher#results()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results()) in the second example, so it can be :

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".?Test (.)");
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path)) {
    lines.forEach(input -> pattern.matcher(input)
            .results()
            .forEach(matcher -> System.out.println("Match: " + matcher.group(1)))
    );
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Or as [@Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50787034/java-8-matching-1-pattern-multiple-times-in-1-line-in-a-file-via-a-filter/50787053?noredirect=1#comment88607655_50787053) mention you can use [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)) with [`Matcher#results()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results()) like so :

```
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path)) {
    lines.flatMap(input ->
            pattern.matcher(input).results()
    ).forEach(matchResult -> System.out.println("Match: " + matchResult.group(1)));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Or even you can read the whole file using Scanner, where you can use [`Scanner::findAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#findAll-java.util.regex.Pattern-) which return a Stream like so :

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(path)) {
    scanner.findAll(pattern).forEach(matchResult ->
            System.out.println("Match: " + matchResult.group(1))
    );
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Outputs

```
Match: 1
Match: 2
Match: 3
```

---

You can take a look at this two back-ports of `results()` and `findAll()` by @Holger :

- [How do I create a Stream of regex matches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28148483/how-do-i-create-a-stream-of-regex-matches/28150956#28150956)
- [Java 8 stream emitting a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42961296/java-8-stream-emitting-a-stream/42978216#42978216)

Comment: Instead of nested `forEach`, you may consider `flatMap`: `lines.flatMap(input -> pattern.matcher(input).results()) .forEach(matchResult -> System.out.println("Match: " + matchResult.group(1)));`. Or even simpler: `try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(path)) { scanner.findAll(pattern).forEach(matchResult -> System.out.println("Match: " + matchResult.group(1))); }`. Since this is the cleanest solution, I’d suggest either, [this back-port of `results()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28150956/2711488) or [this back-port of `findAll()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42978216/2711488) for Java 8.

Comment: When giving this data file, the result is "Test 1" and "Test 1". Not exactly what I expect. BUT - thanks anyway! +1

Comment: Thank you @Holger for the information, I really learn from this I appreciate it

Comment: @tjm1706 I try all the solution I already mention and all returns `Match: 1
Match: 2
Match: 3` can you share the file you test with please?

Comment: @YCF_L - thank you for your answer. I've changed the input file and question.

Comment: @tjm1706 In this case you can just change your regex to `.?Test (\d+)` ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's simple `Test 2 Test 3` does not match the regex `.?Test (.)`

You could add the following `flatMap` before the `map(p::matches)` so that you have your input lines splitted and have `Test` at each beginning of string

```
.flatMap(x -> Arrays.stream(x.split(".?(?=Test)")))
```

---

### Complete Code

```
void addMysteries( Path path, String output) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".?Test (.)");
    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines( path)) {
        lines.flatMap(x -> Arrays.stream(x.split(".?(?=Test)")))
                .map( p::matcher)
                .filter(Matcher::matches)
                .forEach( matcher -> System.out.println("Match: " + matcher.group(1)));
    } catch( Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```