# Splitting Strings in a stream in Java?

Tags: java, string, java-stream

I have an assignment where we're reading textfiles and counting the occurrences of each word (ignoring punctuation). We don't have to use streams but I want to practice using them.

So far I am able to read a text file and put each line in a string, and all the strings in a list using this:

```
try (Stream<String> p = Files.lines(FOLDER_OF_TEXT_FILES)) {
    list = p.map(line -> line.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]", ""))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

However, so far, it simply makes all the lines a single String, so each element of the list is not a word, but a line. Is there a way using streams that I can have each element be a single word, using something like String's split method with regex? Or will I have to handle this outside the stream itself?

Comment: Use flatMap to flatten after splitting

Answer (score 1):

Instead of applying `replaceAll` on a line, do it on words of the line as follows:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Harry is a good cricketer. Tanya is an intelligent student. Bravo!";
        List<String> words = Arrays.stream(str.split("\\s+")).map(s -> s.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]", ""))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(words);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[Harry, is, a, good, cricketer, Tanya, is, an, intelligent, student, Bravo]
```

**Note:** The regex, `\\s+` splits a string on space(s).

Answer (score 0):

I may misunderstood your question. But if you just want comma separated words you can try below code 
Replace `line.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]", "")` with `Arrays.asList(line.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]", "").split(" ")).stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","))`

Again use joining method on the list to get comma separated String of words .

```
String commaSeperated = list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(",")) ;
```

You can perform further operations on the final string as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    String fileName = "file.txt";
        try {
        Map<String, Long> wordCount = Files.lines(Path.of(fileName))
                .flatMap(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split("\\s+")))
                     .filter(w->w.matches("[a-zA-Z]+"))
                     .sorted(Comparator.comparing(String::length)
                            .thenComparing(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER))  
                        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(w -> w, 
         LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.counting()));
        wordCount.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This is relatively simple.  It just splits on white space and counts the words by putting them in a map where the Key is the word and the Value is a long containing the count.

I included a filter to only capture words of nothing but letters.
The way this works is that the `Lines` put into a stream.  Each line is then split into words using `String.split`.  Since this creates an array, the `flatMap` converts all these individual streams of words into a single stream where they are processed.
The work horse of this is the `Collectors.groupingBy` which will group the values in a particular way for each key.  In this case, I specified the `Collectors.counting()` method to increase the count each time the key (i.e. word) appeared.

As an option, I sorted the words first on length and then alphabetically, ignoring case.

Answer (score 0):

First, for each line, we're removing all non-alphanumeric characters (excluding spaces), then we split on space, so all elements are single words. Since we're flatmapping, the stream consists of all words. Then we simply collect using the `groupingBy` collector, and use `counting()` as downstream collector. That'll leaves us with a `Map<String, Long>` were the key is the word and the value is the number of occurrences.

```
list = p
    .flatMap(line -> Arrays.stream(line.replaceAll("[^0-9A-Za-z ]+", "").split("\\s+")))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting());
```

Answer (score 0):

Since line boundaries are irrelevant when want to process *words*, the preferred way is not to bother with splitting into lines, just to split lines into words, but split the file into words in the first place. You can use something like:

```
Map<String,Long> wordsAndCounts;
try(Scanner s = new Scanner(Paths.get(path))) {
    wordsAndCounts = s.findAll("\\w+")
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MatchResult::group, Collectors.counting()));
}
wordsAndCounts.forEach((w,c) -> System.out.println(w+":\t"+c));
```

The `findAll` method of `Scanner` requires Java 9 or newer. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42978216/2711488) contains an implementation of `findAll` for Java 8. This allows to use it on Java 8 and easily migrate to newer versions by just switching to the standard method.

Answer (score 0):

one could use a `Pattern.splitAsStream` to split a string in a performant way and at the same time replace all non word characters before creating a map of occurrence counts:

```
Pattern splitter = Pattern.compile("(\\W*\\s+\\W*)+");
String fileStr = Files.readString(Path.of(FOLDER_OF_TEXT_FILES));

Map<String, Long> collect = splitter.splitAsStream(fileStr)
        .collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), counting()));

System.out.println(collect);
```

For splitting and removal of non word characters we are using the pattern `(\W*\s+\W*)+` where we look for optional non word characters then a space and then again for optional non word characters.

Answer (score 0):

For the entire "read a text file and count each word using streams", I suggest using something like this:

```
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(FOLDER_OF_TEXT_FILES)) {
    lines.flatMap(l -> Arrays.stream(l.split(" ")))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

}
```

There is no need to first collect everything into a list, this can be done inline.
Also it's good that you used try-with-resources.