# How to use regex to match HTML tag contents in Java

Tags: java, regex

**What I want to accomplish:**

I want to match certain explicit content outside of comments.

**An Example:**

```
<div>
    <div>Hello $world$</div>
    <div>Another text <!-- $example$--></div>   
</div>
<div>
    How are $you$?
</div>
<!-- 
<div>
    Lorem ipsum $dolor$ sit
</div>
-->
```

**Words I want to match:** `$world$` , `$you$`

**Words I don't want to match:** `$example$` , `$dolor$`

So far I was only able to match either all or none.

**What I can't do:**

I can't delete all comments because because it's required to provide the source code I filtered.

Comment: Can you provide an example of code which is not working?

Comment: can you specify the Regular expression you used, but didn't provide the results you hoped for?

Comment: Finally I ended with this: `/(?:<!--.*?-->)($.*?$)/gsm` but it definitely not match what i want to match :)

Comment: Add alternation (`/(?:<!--.*?-->)|($.*?$)/gsm`, notice the `|` in the middle) and check if there is anything in the first capturing group

Comment: @DmitryEgorov It did the trick! Thank you. Can you please post your comment as an answer so thanks to that i'll be able to mark my question as resolved.

Comment: @JanNowak feel free to read up on [what to do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add alternation

```
/(?:<!--.*?-->)|($.*?$)/gsm
               ^
```

and check if there is anything in the first capturing group.

Comment: It’s probably a good idea to escape the `$`, especially the second one.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell where you come from with your code, but you need to read your page into a String oder String[] and then run a regular expression over it to extract the Strings you want to filter.

**How to use a stream with regex in java:**

[How do I create a Stream of regex matches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28148483/how-do-i-create-a-stream-of-regex-matches)

**How to use regex in java:**

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm

**Test your regular expression before deploying it:**

https://regexr.com/