# ContainsIgnoreCase in stream filter to count one particular word occurence in list of String

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I want to count a single word occurrence in a List of String in java. Seemingly this task is easy but I met a problem with words which starts by capital letter or contains `,` or `.` at the end of the word.
My method looks like:

```
public static Long countWordOccurence(List<String> wordList, String word) {

    return wordList.stream()
        .filter(s -> word.contains(s))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
        .values()
        .stream()
        .findFirst()
        .orElse((long) -1);
  }
```

Above code works fine for normal scenario but the problem occurs for a corner case like coma at the end of the string like `Test,` or a String which starts by a capital letter.

I am splitting my string list like:

```
Arrays.asList(TEXT_TO_PARSE.split(" "));
```

If it possible I would be grateful to avoid additional dependencies but if it will be necessary I will not despise.

I will be grateful for a suggestion on how to fix my filter clause in a stream to count strings properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several fundamental problems with your code.

- `.filter(s -> word.contains(s))` performs a substring search. Contrary to your question’s title, it does not ignore case. Still, there can be strings of different content passing the filter
- `.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))` creates groups according to the string’s actual content. So when multiple different strings passed the previous filter, multiple groups may exist
- `.values().stream().findFirst()`: since the `groupingBy` created a map with an unspecified ordering, this will pick an arbitrary group. Besides that, it’s a very inefficient way to ask just for the `count()`
- `.orElse((long) -1)` The value `-1` is a very strange fall-back for counting, as the most natural answer would be “zero” when there are no matches.

So a straight-forward solution would be

```
public static long countWordOccurence(List<String> wordList, String word) {
    return Collections.frequency(wordList, word);
}
```

for counting case sensitive matches or

```
public static long countWordOccurence(List<String> wordList, String word) {
    return wordList.stream().filter(word::equalsIgnoreCase).count();
}
```

for counting case insensitive.

But that’s an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) anyway.

When you want to count occurrences of a word in a string, it’s not necessary to split the string into words and to convert the array into a list (by the way, you can [stream over an array directly](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#stream(T%5B%5D))), before performing the actual search.

You can use

```
public static long countWordOccurence(String sentence, String word) {
    if(!word.codePoints().allMatch(Character::isLetter))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(word+" is not a word");
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b"+word+"\\b");
    return p.matcher(sentence).results().count();
}
```

for a count of case sensitive matches and

```
public static long countWordOccurence(String sentence, String word) {
    if(!word.codePoints().allMatch(Character::isLetter))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(word+" is not a word");
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b"+word+"\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    return p.matcher(sentence).results().count();
}
```

for the case insensitive matches. The `\b` pattern denotes word boundaries, which only makes sense if the search string is actually a word. So the methods above have a pre-test for that, which also ensures that the word does not contain characters that could be misinterpreted as regex patterns.

The `results()` method was introduced in Java 9. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28150956/2711488) shows a solution for creating such a stream under Java 8, however, for such a simple task as counting the occurrences, the alternative would be not to use streams here:

```
public static long countWordOccurence(String sentence, String word) {
    if(!word.codePoints().allMatch(Character::isLetter))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(word+" is not a word");
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b"+word+"\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    int count = 0;
    for(Matcher m = p.matcher(sentence); m.find(); count++) {}
    return count;
}
```

Comment: removed my answer, yours covers more

Comment: @Holger Impressive answer, thank you so much for your commitment.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko your answer was useful either. You could leave it. Thank you so much for commitment.

Comment: @Martin it's OK. I am glad Holger answered your questions :)