# How to input a list of numbers and assign it to a variable

Tags: java, arrays, int, variable-assignment

Below is the script i wrote to attempt to input a list of numbers(integers) and assign it to a variable

```
import java.util.ArrayList;   
import java.util.Arrays;

public class AssignList
{
    public static void main(String[] args)    
    {   
      //int[] b =Arrays.toString(args);     //my attempt to assign an input to variable b
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args)); 

         int[] a = {5, 2, 4, 1};            //how to print out integers
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));  
     }
}
```

i can input and print out a list of numbers but i haven't been able to figure out how to assign it to a variable.

---

I dont mean my question is necessarily different from the one linked by the commenter, it's just i havent been able to figure it out even after looking at it.

I think the format of `args` is java.lang.String.  Assuming that one will execute the script by typing `java AssignList 5241`, i would like to be able to assign the input `5241` as an array so that i can pick out each element by indexing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting String Array to an Integer Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838781/converting-string-array-to-an-integer-array)

Comment: "java AssignList 5241" -> the args received in main is a string array with exactly one entry: "5241". If you want each digit to be separated you have to suppliy it by "java AssignList 5 2 4 1" (note the spaces), so the args param contains four  entries. Afterwards you can convert each (String) entry into an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

args is a String array. 
If you write "java AssignList 5241" you will have one element "5241" in your array, you can access this element by args[0]

If you write "java AssignList 5 2 4 1" you will have 4 elements in your array.
You can convert a String array to a int array by converting every single element.

So if you use "java AssignList 5 2 4 1"

```
    int[] intArray = new int[args.length];
    for (int i =0;i<intArray.length;i++){
        intArray[i]=Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
    }
```

And if you use "java AssignList 5241"

```
    String arg = args[0];
    String[] argsArray = arg.split("");
    int[] intArray = new int[argsArray.length];
    for (int i =0;i<intArray.length;i++){
        intArray[i]=Integer.parseInt(argsArray[i]);
    }
```