# How to convert values stored in the String array to Integer array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Here I want to convert sting array values into integer array,Need to store all string values into integer array, Here is the string array:

```
private String[] aa = {"70","80","99","140","150","199","200","300",
                       "349","350","400","499","500","501","900","1000","1100","1200"};
```

Comment: What is your attempt so far ?

Comment: Duplicate of :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881458/converting-a-string-array-into-an-int-array-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the array and convert it to int.

```
int []intArray = new int[strArray.length];
int i = 0;
for(String s : strArray)
  intArray[i ++] = Integer.parseInt(s);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intArray));
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're on Java8, you could do:

```
int[] array = Stream.of(aa).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    int[] bb = new int[aa.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < aa.length; i++) {
        bb[i] = Integer.parseInt(aa[i]);
    }
```

http://ideone.com/uJCAX2