# Array Program for Java

Tags: java, arrays

```
package myProjects;

import java.util.*;  

public class Acm3 {     
    static int numberOfFriends;
    static int rowOfChocolate;
    static int columnOfChocolate;
    static String division;
    static Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);  

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("How many friends you want to distribute?");
        numberOfFriends = myScanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("How do you want to distribute?");
        division = myScanner.next();
        String[] myArray = division.split("\\s");
        int[] myArray1 = new int[numberOfFriends];
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i <= numberOfFriends; i++); {       
             myArray1[i] = Integer.parseInt(myArray[i]);
             System.out.print(myArray1[i]);
        }       
    }
}
```

I am trying to transfer `String` array to `Int` Array.I have a string array and want to convert each elements into int and finally into array. Anyone who can help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a String array into an int Array in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881458/converting-a-string-array-into-an-int-array-in-java)

Comment: Please format your code next (time indent 4 spaces or use the {} button). Also note that you have a stray semicolon after your loop, so the block in curly braces runs only once, not once for each array element as you might expect.

Comment: What error do you get ? On which line ?

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] intValues = Arrays.asList(myArray)
                       .stream()
                       .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                       .toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intValues));
```