# How to use valueOf to convert a string array to a int array?

Tags: java, arrays

I want to convert following list into a int array. I have tried to use `valueof` but I don't know how to use it. I don't want to parse it.

I have a string array here:
`String[] arr1 = new String[]{"5","5","15","5","10","10", "5", "10", "20", "15"};`

Here is the code I tried:

`int num = Integer.valueOf(arr1);`

**I am getting a error message:**

```
error: no suitable method found for valueOf(String[])
    int num = Integer.valueOf(arr1);
                     ^
    method Integer.valueOf(String) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; String[] cannot be converted to String)
    method Integer.valueOf(int) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; String[] cannot be converted to int)
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
1 error
```

Comment: How would I use valueOf?

Comment: If you want to convert those string representations of numbers to ints, then you *do* want to parse them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I know parsing is probably easier but I am told to not use it.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I am new to programming so I was confused.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a String array into an int Array in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881458/converting-a-string-array-into-an-int-array-in-java)

Comment: It is a different question since you can't parse. Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to map every value in the `arr1` array to an `int`, and the result should be an **`int[]`** (not one `int`). Stream the array, map the elements to an `int`, and then invoke `toArray`. Like,

```
int[] numArr = Arrays.stream(arr1).mapToInt(Integer::valueOf).toArray();
```

Note that invoking `valueOf` in this way is still an example of parsing the `String` to an `int`.

Comment: How would I use valueOf?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I am new to programming so I was confused.

Answer (score 1):

Using Streams:

```java
int[] intArray = Stream.of(arr1).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, as mentioned I do not want to parse at all. Is there any other way to do it.

Comment: `valueOf` calls `parseInt` internally so not sure you have a choice

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I am new to programming so I was confused.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through each element of `Array` and convert it into `Int` and push it into `IntArray`.

```
String[] arr1 = new String[]{"5","5","15","5","10","10", "5", "10", "20", "15"};
int[] intArr = new int[arr1.length];

for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  intArr[i] = Integer.valueOf(arr1[i]);
}
```

`valueOf` internally uses `parseInt`

```
public static Integer valueOf(String s) throws NumberFormatException {
    return Integer.valueOf(parseInt(s, 10));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, as mentioned I do not want to parse at all. Is there any way I can do it using valueOf?

Comment: Yes, you can use `valueOf`  instead of `parseInt`. `valueOf` returns an int and not the int arr. That's why you need to push it into int arr either using for each or Stream as other answers has suggested.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I am new to programming so I was confused.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it without using `valueOf` or `parseInt`.

```java
      String[] arr1 = new String[] { "5", "5", "15", "5", "10", "10", "5", "10"
      };


      int[] vals = Arrays.stream(arr1).mapToInt(str -> str.chars().reduce(0,
            (val, ch) -> val * 10 + (ch - '0'))).toArray();

      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(vals));
```

Here are its limitations:

1. If your strings contain characters other than digits.  It will quietly give you the wrong answer.
2. It does not handle negative values.
3. It will throw an exception if any of the individual numbers exceed `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

My recommendation would be to use `Integer.valueOf`.  That is what it's for.