# How do you find the average of the max and min value in a String?

Tags: java

I am currently experimenting with Strings in Java.

For example you have a string `"1234 Hello 56789"` and now you want to calculate the average of the max and min value, which is `(1234/5678)/2 = 58023`.

How do you do that?

I tried `Integer.parseInt` which gives me an error.

I tried `replaceAll("[^0-9]", "")` which does not get me the min and max and therefore the avg. It outputs 123456789 which I do not want.

I also tried `replaceAll("[^0-9]", "").split("\\D+")` which just gives me `1234 56789`, but I don't know how to get the min and max.

Comment: I would start by forgetting the min, max, average parts. Instead, focus on "how can I extract numbers from a string"? Once you've done that part, the rest is simple maths. You probably want to think about whether your string can contain non-integers, whether you want to permit thousands separators in numbers, etc.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, it's very difficult regarding to locale representation of non-integer values. How can we predict what is the number 1,0 vs 1.0;  or 1_000 instead of 1.000 OR 1,000.00? Not so simple, isn't it?

Comment: @zlakad: No, it's definitely not simple. But that's the sort of thing the OP should be asking themselves in terms of defining their requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I also tried `replaceAll("[^0-9]", "").split("\\D+")`

This is a good first step. It will give you an array of strings (`String[]`). It is probably a good idea to then convert this to an `int[]`. See [Converting a String array into an int Array in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881458/converting-a-string-array-into-an-int-array-in-java/26164167)

Once you have an `int[]`, you can calculate the max and the min by referring to  [Finding the max/min value in an array of primitives using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484347/finding-the-max-min-value-in-an-array-of-primitives-using-java)

By the way, the average is not (1234/5678)/2. It is (1234 **+** 5678)/2